# Static variable initialization in Constructor java

Tags: java, static, constructor

i want to understand from the below code y the value of static variable b was not initialized and though the value was initialized in the constructor.

```
public class A {
       private static B b = null;
       public A() {
           if (b == null)
             b = new B();
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           b.func();
       }
    }
```

Thanks
Punith

Comment: Because you've made the initialization of `b` dependent upon the creation of an instance of `A`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [static variable initialization java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642347/static-variable-initialization-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never call the A() constructor.
main function is static, that means that it doesnt "belong" to an instance of A.
So when you enter main, no instance of A has been created so A constructor has never been called and b is still null.

You should get a NullPointerException if you run this code.

If you add
    new A(); 
before the b.func(); then you will be okay (code will still be odd)

Answer (score 7):

Wrong - do it like this:

```
public class A {
       private static B b = null;

       static {
             b = new B();
       }

       public A() {
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           b.func();
       }
    }
```

Comment: It would be more helpful, I'm sure, if you could elaborate on why it's wrong to do the way in the OP posted.

Comment: But this is semantically different, right? In the code the OP posted, the field is not initialized unless an object is actually cerated.

Comment: Guys, i want to know that before the main method is called constructor will be called. so object will be initialized. or is the above statement false ??

Comment: Constructors are called for instances, not static variables.

Comment: No, constructor is not called before `main()`, btw you can test these things simply adding `System.out.println()` ;-)

Comment: @duffymo: I do NOT understand what you are trying to say, really.

Comment: Guys, i want to know that before the main method is called constructor will be called. so object will be initialized. or is the above statement false --- > my statement was wrong. understood it from @Brad answer

Comment: I gave you the answer.  Initialize it in a static block.  Your code was wrong.  Did you try and run what I gave you?  Please do.

Answer (score 3):

I think your question has two parts:

> 1) Why the value of static variable b was not initialized and though
>   the value was initialized in the constructor?

Ans: First thing is that no constructor is called before main(). Constructors are called in main(). Whenever in main() you use `new` as :

```
public static void main(String args[]){
MyClass myclass= new MyClass()
}
```

then only constructor is called.

In your code static variable b was not initialized becoz u are initializing it in constructor A() but this constructor has never been called. You can call A() constructor in your code as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
          A a=new A(); // constructor gets called here.
           b.func();
       }
```

> 2)  what is proper way of initializing a static variable?

The right way to initialize a static variable is to use static Initialization Blocks rather than to initialize them in constructors as shown in answer given by duffymo above.

```
static {
  b = new B();
 }
```

You can also use:

```
public class A {
       private static B b = new B();

       public A() {
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           b.func();
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question asked to help you "understand why" the behaviour was as it was. The reason is that the constructor for Class A is not called when you invoke a static method `main()`.

If you were to instantiate an object of type `A` then the constructor would be called and you reference to `B` initialised.

I would recomend always instantiating a Class before executing it from `static void main()` as a matter of good practise. If you start using a frameworks (e.g. Spring), you are better off creating instances of your classes than just writing static methods which is akin to writing procedural code.

A solution without resorting to static initialisers and following the principle outline here, is...

```
public class A {
    private static B b = null;

    public A() {
        if (b == null)
          b = new B();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.callFunc();
    }

    public void callFunc() {
        b.func();
    }
}
```

As you can see you need a way to reference the `b.func() method` so I have added a `a.callFunc()` for this reason